# Google+1 on another line instead of inline with other social icons. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Essentially, I have a Social Icon area on my product page. For some reason, the Google+ icon is on its' own line, despite there being plenty of space for it. So I'm very confused.

My jsfiddle is at:

http://jsfiddle.net/g4v9X/

```
<div id="___plusone_0" style="text-indent: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: transparent; border-style: none; float: none; line-height: normal; font-size: 1px; vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block; width: 90px; height: 20px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"><iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="position: static; top: 0px; width: 90px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 20px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I0_1395062409478" name="I0_1395062409478" src="https://apis.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&amp;size=medium&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Frsatestamle.dminsite.com&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Frsatestamle.dminsite.com%2Ffelco-pruner-original-model-2%2Fp%2F2FEL%2F&amp;gsrc=3p&amp;ic=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.wahzyPoGp9Y.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Fz%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAItRSTMR2QIL_JJ2Bswf2u9LuAHHGYIsVQ#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Conload&amp;id=I0_1395062409478&amp;parent=http%3A%2F%2Frsatestamle.dminsite.com&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=38291840" data-gapiattached="true" title="+1"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: It appears to only be doing this at the widest resolution, so maybe check to see what the difference is for that break point. Regardless, your JSFiddle is *really* difficult to use; you shouldn't paste your entire site there, especially not all the HTML, JS, and CSS in one box. There are separate boxes for each of those for a reason. Try narrowing down the JSFiddle code to just the relevant bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always change it position by giving it an ID value and then using `position: relative;` to assign it to it's proper position. Hope my idea helped.